Azure Feature Flags Filter Toggle not working
I have a requirement to enable a certain feature within our application for a list of 'storeIds' held within a configured list within the Azure Feature Management screen within Azure.
This is how I have configured within Azure:


I have created an out of the box Azure Function with the following custom code:
Program.cs
using Functions.FeatureFlag;
using Functions.FeatureFlag.Features;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
     {
         builder.AddAzureAppConfig(opts =>
         {
             
         });
     })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();
        services.AddFeatureManagement()
                .AddFeatureFilter<StoreIdFilter>();

    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

StoreIdFilter.cs
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement;

namespace Functions.FeatureFlag.Features
{
    [FilterAlias(nameof(StoreIdFilter))]
    public class StoreIdFilter : IContextualFeatureFilter<MyCustomFilterContext>
    {
        public Task<bool> EvaluateAsync(FeatureFilterEvaluationContext featureFilterContext, MyCustomFilterContext appContext)
        {
            var storeIds = featureFilterContext.Parameters["StoreIds"].ToString().Split(',');

            return Task.FromResult(storeIds.Contains(appContext.InputNumber.ToString()));
        }
    }

    public class MyCustomFilterContext
    {
        public int InputNumber { get; set; }
    }
}

Function1.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement;
using Functions.FeatureFlag.Features;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration;

namespace Functions.FeatureFlag
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        private readonly IFeatureManagerSnapshot _featureManagerSnapshot;
        private readonly IConfigurationRefresher _configurationRefresher;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IFeatureManagerSnapshot featureManagerSnapshot, IConfigurationRefresherProvider refresherProvider)
        {
            _featureManagerSnapshot = featureManagerSnapshot;
            _configurationRefresher = refresherProvider.Refreshers.First();
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            try
            {
                var featureFlagName = "AssumedDeliveriesFeature";

                // Retrieve storeId from the query string
                if (!req.Query.TryGetValue("storeId", out var storeIdValue) || !int.TryParse(storeIdValue, out var storeId))
                {
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid or missing 'storeId' query parameter.");
                }

                // Use the storeId in the feature flag evaluation
                string message = await _featureManagerSnapshot.IsEnabledAsync(featureFlagName, new MyCustomFilterContext { InputNumber = storeId })
                    ? $"Feature ENABLED for store id {storeId}"
                    : $"Feature NOT ENABLED for store id {storeId}";

                return new OkObjectResult(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while checking feature flags.");
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
}

Postman Response for StoreID that exists in list

Postman Response for StoreId not in list

This works as expected, however.... When I go back to the Portal and toggle the 'enabled' button to 'disabled' like so:

I still get a response that indicates that this feature is enabled for a store, I would expect a blanket false to be returned for every 'storeId' that is passed through at this point, as we have switched the feature off globally:

How can I ensure that if the toggle is disabled, I get the response I am expecting from my code?

Is the issue resolved?@JsonStatham
